# Energy Bar in Unity

Tags: unity, javascript

I want to display a debug message when the progress bar is loaded fully and I have a button "refresh", when I click this it should reload the progress bar. Here is the code I have tried:

```
var energyBar : GUIStyle ;
var bgImage : Texture2D; // background image that is 256 x 32
var fgImage : Texture2D; // foreground image that is 256 x 32
static var playerEnergy = 1.0; // a float between 0.0 and 1.0

function Start() {
}

function Update() {
    playerEnergy=Time.time *0.02;
    if(playerEnergy<=0)
    {
        Debug.Log("stopped working");
    }
}

function OnGUI () {
    // Create one Group to contain both images , the first two numbers define the on    screen placement
    GUI.BeginGroup (Rect (10,10,256,32));

    // Draw the background image
    GUI.Box (Rect (0,0,256,32), bgImage, energyBar);

    // Create a second Group which will be clipped
    // We want to clip the image and not scale it, which is why we need the second Group
     GUI.BeginGroup (Rect (0,0,playerEnergy * 256, 32));

     // Draw the foreground image
     GUI.Box (Rect (0,0,256,32), fgImage, energyBar);

     if(GUI.Button(new Rect(100,200,60,30),"Refresh"))
     {
         // code to Restart the progress bar
     }

    // End both Groups
    GUI.EndGroup ();
    GUI.EndGroup ();
}
```

From the above code I am able to display the progress bar, but the problem is that the "refresh" button is not getting displayed and I need help in reloading the progress bar when refresh button is clicked. I also need to print the debug message when the progress bar is fully loaded, but here the debug message is getting displayed when the progress bar starts loading. Can anybody please help me out.

Here I have attached the texture also

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a "debug my code" question and considered off-topic here. You're aware that `Time.time` is the elapsed time since you started the game? Of course it will start at `0` and `0 * 0.02` is `0`, therefore your debug message will get printed right at the start.

Comment: How can i get it solved

Comment: You could try to improve your question, so that it's answerable and also useful for future visitors of the site. You also need to be more specific with your problem: What works, what doesn't? What should happen? Should the energy-bar deplete over time (what timeframe?) and what should a click on the "Refresh" button do? There also seems to be a contradiction in your question: *the "refresh" button is not getting displayed* and *when refresh button is clicked*. How do you click a button that isn't being displayed?

Comment: I mean the button "Refresh " is not getting displayed

Comment: Then how do you click it?

Comment: Although it isn't clear what they are asking I feel there is a genuine query we can help with here. @user1509674 please take care and explain **one** thing that does not work. We can more easily help you if we are only solving one issue per question.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify clearly what you are trying to accomplish. You speak about progress bar but use a `playerEnergy` variable. Are you trying to fill or to deplete the bar?

In any case this line looks suspicious.

```
playerEnergy=Time.time *0.02;
```

This line has two potential problems (that we cannot state properly until we know exactly what you want to do). The first one is that it ignores previous energy values, which *seems* is not what you want to do. Second, it relies on Time.time, which is a variable that always increases over time, which again *seems* is not what you want.

I am going to take a **wild guess** that what you want to do is something like this.

```
playerEnergy-=Time.deltaTime *0.02;
```

This line of code decreases the value of the variable playerEnergy steadily over time. Check [deltaTime](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) for details.

In order to reset the 'progression bar', just set playerEnergy back to 1.0 again.

Comment: angarg12 : From the above code Iam not getting the button displayed

Comment: Playerenergy is the name of the variable given

Comment: I didn't address the button, only the bar.

Comment: The button got displayed,As you said I gave the code to reset the progress bar inside the button click,its not working                                                             f(GUI.Button(new Rect(500,500,50,30),btnTexture))
{
   playerEnergy=1.0; }

Comment: @user1509674 Your button is probably rendered off-screen. Try to increase viewport-size or position the button at `0,0` for testing.

Comment: @bummzack I got the button displayed,but when I click on the button the progress bar should get reloaded.Inside the if(GUI.Button....) I have written the code playerEnergy=1.0; but its not working